# Android Notification While App is in Background Show the Notification Briefly like iOS

Tags: android, notifications

Working with Android GCM Notifications for the first time.  Getting the notification to appear in the Notification list no problem, but would like the notification to appear to the user for a short time when it is placed in the list.  Is there a way to do this?

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intentNotify = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intentNotify.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentNotify.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentNotify.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        intentNotify.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSmallIcon(notificationDrawableIconID)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

[ Addition ]
Thanks for the comments so far, maybe I am missing something here, but on iOS, when a notification comes in AND the app is in the background, the notification displays to the user for a short time.  The user then pulls down the notification list, selects the notification and the app comes to the front and processes the notification.

On Android, we have all of this working fine, except the part when the app is in the background and we place the notification in the list, it does not display to the user for a short time.

On command it to show it?  How is this done.  Have done a bit of reading, but have not seen how to do this.

[ Addition 2 ]

Turned on ticker and this is not working on Lollipop.  Works on others, the message ticker displays for a bit and goes away.

Comment: well show it, and count to your duration and kill it.

Comment: Ok thanks, how to show it?

Comment: try these and see, on your notification when its in the background [setOngoing(boolean ongoing)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29) & [setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean onlyAlertOnce)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce%28boolean%29) & [setPriority(int pri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority%28int%29) , tweak them to see if it will match your need